# How to jmap -permstat to an hprof image

Tags: java, profiling, jmap

I wonder how can I fetch stats of permgen using `jmap -permstat` to a hprof dump.

I know it can be done against a PID.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible. We need to get that stats from a PID or Core file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html

```
jmap [ option ] pid
jmap [ option ] executable core
jmap [ option ] [server-id@]remote-hostname-or-IP
```